# How do I FILTER cells based on two drop-down list conditions?

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I need a FILTER formula to get an output of the cells within the range of the two labels matching the conditions from the two drop-down lists.

For example, given the below sheet, I need the output to be what's highlighted, given the two conditions from the drop-down lists:

[image]

I also need to be able to add more date rows, expanding downward.

I've tried using QUERY:

```
=TRANSPOSE(QUERY(Accounts!B2:F, "SELECT * WHERE B="""&B2&""" ",1))
```

This only gives me the row of contents (apple, carrot, cake, steak, soda).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you can find my solution:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cWBLLmJx6mTlYrvPRvRE_y9NpBOJj_ILBgXmoB9suv4/copy

1. Note that when you merge cells, the value is only in the top one or the leftmost one. So if you have multiple rows for each data, you should multiplicate these cells.
   I make additional column for this - first date I just copy and below it I insert a formula: (in H5)
   =if(isblank(A5),H4,A5) - it says - if cell in column A is empty, take value from above, but if you find something there, put it here. Then I copy this formula down the sheet.

Then it gets easier.

2. To filter with data validation you have to first find right column using formulas INDEX and MATCH and then filter it against data values in additional column.

[image]

Does it work for you?

Comment: This works, thank you! I figure I can just hide the column with all the duplicate dates.